# Postgresql: Change COUNT value based on condition

Tags: postgresql

So this is my table in database:
Worker X have this work result `BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-06'`:
[image]

What I want to do is to count the number of work days but my condition is that if `(nb_heures + nb_heures_s) > 4` I count it 1 day but if `(nb_heures + nb_heures_s) <= 4` I count it 0.5 day.
So the result I must get from this table 5.5 work days and not 6.
I tried this query but it's not working well:

```
SELECT 
    count(CASE WHEN (nb_heures + nb_heures_s) > 4 THEN 1 END) as full_day_work,
    count(CASE WHEN (nb_heures + nb_heures_s) <= 4 THEN 0.5 END) as half_day_work
FROM pointage_full pf
WHERE date_pointage BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-06'
AND pf.id_salarie = 5
```

How can I reach my objectif ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT(expr)` always returns a `bigint`, as it simply returns the number of rows for which `expr` is not NULL.

You can use `SUM` instead :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (nb_heures + nb_heures_s) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0.5 END) as number_of_days
FROM pointage_full pf
WHERE date_pointage BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-06';
```